# how to view the name of credit and debit in same table from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to tables, table accounts and table entities, the credit and debit are number = id in table account, 
i want to write a query and the result is the name of credit number and the name of debit number and date and value from table entities

some data from tables:

```
table entities:    
id  credit   debit  value  date
1   100      101    5000   01/01/2014

table accounts:    
id   name
100  Mark
101  Jone
```

this some data from my database. All what I need a query to show this result:

```
1, Mark, Jone, 5000, 01/01/2014
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant parts of your database schema.

Comment: table accounts: id, name, phone.
table entity: id , credit, debit, value, date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to join the accounts table twice (once for the credit name, and once for the debit name):

```
SELECT
    e.id, 
    credit_account.name AS CreditName, 
    debit_account.name  AS DebitName, 
    e.value, 
    e.date 
FROM entities AS e
JOIN accounts AS credit_account ON e.credit = credit_account.id
JOIN accounts AS debit_account  ON e.debit  = debit_account.id
```

This query produces this output:

```
id          CreditName           DebitName            value       date
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------
1           Mark                 Jone                 5000        2014-01-01
```

It assumes there is a value in both the credit and debit columns for each row in the entities table. If one of them can be missing you might want to use`LEFT JOIN`instead to get a null value in the column with the missing value.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f9e34/1)